# Populate join table using seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app I have three tables: `users`, `roles`, and `users_roles`.

In my `seeds.rb` file I have the following ruby code:

```
# create super admin role
Role.create!([{name: "Super Admin", description: "Super Admin (can do anything)"}])
# create user
User.create!([{name: "Cameron", email: "cameron.drysdale@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$k4FPOZlVmy.hIM5z1scFYeFc8cNcVGpq..MU0529LlSGylEqYLaqC"}])
# make user super admin
User::HABTM_Roles.create!([{user_id: 1, role_id: 1}])
```

However it fails on that last line: `User::HABTM_Roles.create!`

How do I add the data into the join table?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
User.first.roles << Role.first
```

Comment: Hey pal, could you explain what that code does? I'm new to Ruby, thanks.

Comment: I think your user model has_many roles. It means, it can contain an array of roles objects. This line pushes the first role at the end of the roles array in the first user.

Comment: `id` is not necessarily `1` though if the seeds have been run a couple of times. Better to get the `user` from `user = User.create(...)`

Comment: Well, I used the ids the user provided in the question.